# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I need help with a little array assignment that I am currently doing. So far I managed to correct alof of code but this one problem still remains..

```
public class AssignmentArray1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a[][] = new int[ 10 ][ 5 ];

        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < a[ i ].length; j++ ) {
                a[ j ][ i ] = j;
            }
        }
        for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < a[ i ].length; j++ )
                System.out.printf( "%d ", a[ j ][ i ] );
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

What's wrong with this? I can't understand why I'm getting the error message

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 at assignmentarray1.AssignmentArray1.main(AssignmentArray1.java:25)

So obviously something is wrong with `a[ j ][ i ] = j;`? But exactly what is?

Comment: Replace `a[ j ][ i ]` by `a[ i ][ j ]` (in both loops)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have your indexes swapped by accident for the `a` array.

This:

```
            a[ j ][ i ] = j;
```

Should be:

```
            a[ i ][ j ] = j;
```

And this:

```
            System.out.printf( "%d ", a[ j ][ i ] );
```

Should be:

```
            System.out.printf( "%d ", a[ i ][ j ] );
```

Answer (score 1):

The ending conditions in your two loops are the wrong way round. The easiest way to fix this is to change the assignment as follows:

```
            a[ i ][ j ] = i;
```

You also need to fix the second pair of nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

Change from,

```
a[ j ][ i ] = j;
```

To,

```
a[ i ][ j ] = j;
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.length = 10` and `a[i].length=5` as per array declaration.

Now, in this for loop

```
for ( int i = 0; i < a.length; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < a[ i ].length; j++ ) {
            a[ j ][ i ] = j;
        }
    }
```

as per array boundary `0<=i<10` and `0<=j<5` should be satisfied, but this `a[ j ][ i ] = j;` statement violates the boundary condition of the array because `i` can go upto 9 but allowed only in the range [0,5) so `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` is obvious.

Check your for loops and fix the indexing.